How to reload a site that was previously opened in js
im trying to refresh a url that is opened until it is canceled by the user manually
This is the actual code that i used - Used for an exploit in most chrome blocking extensions that unblock a website after cancel. your text
<html>
<script>

let site = prompt("Site?")
let open_site = window.open(site)
while (true)  {
window.open_site.reload()
}

</script>
</html>


In JavaScript, you can reload a webpage using the location.reload() method. This method reloads the current URL, just as if the user clicked the browser's reload button

I was talking about opening a url, and reloading it. Is that possible in JS?

Yes, you can open a URL in JavaScript and then reload it using a combination of the window.open() method and the location.reload() method.
var newWindow = window.open('https://example.com');
if (newWindow) {
setTimeout(function() {
    newWindow.location.reload();
}, 5000);

} else {
console.log("Popup blocked by the browser");

}

As per your code you are giving a prompt to user and then trying to open the entered input. You can use window.location.href for open the entered website


<html>
  <script>
    let site = prompt("Site?") ;
    window.location.href = site
  </script>
</html>;



